# I am having issues with aws s3 decrypting my file in SSE-C encryption technique

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i encrypted my file using SSE-C encryption technique from s3 aws.
but when i tried to decrypt it, the following error popups.
i am using the same keys which i used when creating encryption.
the error is as follows:

```
InvalidRequest
The object was stored using a form of Server Side Encryption. The correct parameters must be provided to retrieve the object.
```

any suggestions on this please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get aws sever-side encrypted object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343662/how-to-get-aws-sever-side-encrypted-object)